# Get outer xml structure of xml file to a string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I don't know if this is possible or not with just javascript/jquery. I have a number of xml files that I usually read and disply with xpath, but the xml files are structured with HTML elements like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <catalog>
 <outcome>
    <title>1.1</title>
    <section>
    <p>some text as an intro:
      <ul>
        <li>part of list</li>
        <li>part of list</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p>more text</p>
    </section>
</outcome>

<outcome>
 <title>1.2</title>
 <section>
    <p>some text as an intro:
      <ul>
        <li>part of list</li>
        <li>part of list</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p>more text</p>
    </section>
</outcome>
</catalog>
```

I want to display all children and descendants of a select  element. Using javascript, I know how to load the xml and select the element I need, and I know how to loop through nodes, but is it possible just to get a node and its descendants as a string? I could then just take the string and append a div like element.html("string"). I would let my css style the elements as needed. 
Is this possible with javascript? I know xsl could do this as a whole page, but I need just a small part of a large xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it fairly simply using jQuery by treating it as html

```
$(function() {
  $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('outcome').each(function() {
      $('body').append($(this).html());
    });
  }, 'html');
});
```

If you need to manipulate the new html prior to inserting it ( like adding classes etc) that is also failry trivial

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxTshyZPuznl92O1dlqo?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: that is great - can I filter it by the content of the <title> element. In the example, I only need outcome with the <title> element that contains "1.1". I was trying to use `var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            var str = serializer.serializeToString(xml);
            alert(str);` I was selecting the `path` to the Title element

Comment: can use jQuery methods to filter out what you want. You may also need to use `$.parseXML()` , seems hard to change out the `title` to another tag. Internals of jQuery may be treating it as xml doc

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. when I filter by title, I only get the contents of the title element, none of the children. Hmm

Comment: right, have to look back up to the `outcome` when you find the right title, can just use `parent()`